# Square of the squeezing operator

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hamilton-jacobi-equation

What is the square of the squeezing operator $S(z)=\exp[\frac12\left((z(a^{\dagger})^{ 2}−z^\ast a^2\right)]$?

I mean, with $z \in \mathbb{R}$, what is
$S(Z)S(Z)$?
Is there any formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is a double squeeze, with $z\to 2z$, since the two operators in the exponents commute with each other (!), so you can simply CBH-*add* them,
$$
S(z)S(z)= S(2z).
$$

You may also see this (in overkill, but good to know for more elaborate combinations with the displacement operator) by squaring the middle line matrix of (3.5) in Fisher, R. A., Nieto, M. M., & Sandberg, V. D. (1984). "Impossibility of naively generalizing squeezed coherent states",  *Physical Review* **D29** (6), 1107.

The idea is to map the oscillator operators $a^\dagger a^\dagger$, $-aa$ and $a^\dagger a +1/2$ to the generators of SU(1,1), and then work out the combination of the exponentials as 2x2 matrix multiplications, in the easier-to-handle *faithful* 2x2 matrix representation of SU(1,1). Any group relation holding for this matrix rep will then hold for the oscillator realization!

(See a simple application in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/312818/66086).)

Comment: It's so obvious as to be unnecessary, but this also means $S(z_1)S(z_2)=S(z_1+z_2)$. So any pair of squeezes (or really any _sequence_ of squeezes) is equivalent to a single squeeze.

Comment: Of course! the exponent is linear in the *z* s! Its an abelian structure. The fun only starts with the in production of the *D* s...

Comment: @Semiclassical   Apologies, maybe I was too glib in my comment. My answer above is right, but, for two parameters *z* and *w*, in the 2x2 matrix representation referred to, $[\begin{pmatrix} 0&z\\z^* &0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&w\\w^* &0 \end{pmatrix}]\neq 0$ so I won't vouch for a completely abelian structure, as in my comment...